# unfortunately the app has stopped Android studio and there is no Error

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

[image]

In android monitor it's make this error like in the picture and I can't understand why is the error in the XML ?
the code no problem with it 
can the picture that i added it make this error?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val ListOffood = ArrayList<Food>()
var adpter:foodAdapter=null!!

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    ListOffood.add(Food("sandwis","m3 t7eneh",R.drawable.ic_stat_name))
    ListOffood.add(Food("sandwis","m3 t7eneh",R.drawable.ic_stat_name))
    ListOffood.add(Food("sandwis","m3 t7eneh",R.drawable.ic_stat_name))
    ListOffood.add(Food("sandwis","m3 t7eneh",R.drawable.ic_stat_name))
    ListOffood.add(Food("sandwis","m3 t7eneh",R.drawable.ic_stat_name))

    adpter=foodAdapter(this,ListOffood)
    graidV.adapter=adpter
}

class foodAdapter: BaseAdapter {
    var ListOffood=ArrayList<Food>()
    var context: Context?=null
    constructor(context: Context, ListOffood:ArrayList<Food>):super(){
        this.context=context
        this.ListOffood=ListOffood
    }


    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val food = ListOffood[p0]
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.foodlist,p2,false)
        view.textV.text=food.name
        view.imageV.setImageResource(food.image!!)

        return view
    }


    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return ListOffood[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return ListOffood.size

    }


}

}
```

Comment: It will be better for you to copy and paste the code here than just using a picture. Also don't just post the error. Post your code too

Comment: Mark - Line#16 of MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `adapter` should be use a [late-initialized](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) property or a nullable property. Otherwise, you will get a `KotlinNullPointerException` by the [NPE-lovers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) operator `!!`, for example:

```
//                     v---cast `null` to any type will throws NullPointerException
var adpter:foodAdapter=null!!
```

Should be a [late-initialized](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) property:

```
lateinit var adpter:foodAdapter
```

**OR** a nullable property:

```
var adapter:foodAdapter? = null
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [holi-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269024/unfortunately-the-app-has-stopped-android-studio-and-there-is-no-error#45269512) answer, Kotlin unlike Java tries to be a [null safe language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#null-safety).

Unless explicitly defined all variables in Kotlin are not nullable. Therefore if you wish to have a variable that can hold a `null` value you will need to add `?` after the type name to indicate this is the case.

```
var canBeNull: String? = null
var canNotBeNull: String = null // Won't compile
var canNotBeNull2: String = null!! // Will crash and burn at runtime
```

In your example you were forcing the compiler to accept the `null` value into your `adapter` variable which led to the runtime NPE.

The `!!` syntax should only be used when you are sure that the value *will not* be `null` but the compiler is unable to make that distinction. This can be the case when using 3rd party libraries that are written in Java.